# An example for using Existential and Universal in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this common-sense knowledge:

- Only birds fly.
- All mammal are either ‘a’ OR ‘b’.

How can I write it in prolog as rule and fact, by using both way **Existential** and **universal** (i.e using `forall` and `\+`)?

Pigeon is a birds: `birds (Pigeon).`

Dog is ‘b’: `b(dog).`

dogfight is a dog: `dog(dogfight).`

Finally I should answer these 3 questions:

Can Pigeon fly? `?- fly(Pigeon)` answer should be `true`

Can dogfight fly? `?- fly(Fifi)` answer should be `false`

Is dogfight a mammal?: `?- mammal(fifi)`  answer should be `true`

Comment: How does `mammal(fifi)` tell you whether `dogfight` is a mammal? Your examples seem a bit confused. Also note that in Prolog a token that starts with lower case is constant (an *atom* in Prolog), and it is variable if it starts with a capital letter.

Comment: The notion of "Only birds fly" doesn't necessarily mean (on its own) that *all* birds can fly. I assume, though, in this case that it does? The exclusion of other animals flying (*e.g.*, "Dogs don't fly") is established through the *absence* of any facts or rules that indicate that they would. So you don't necessarily need `\+` for something like that. And to indicate that *All birds can fly* can be expressed as, *If `X` is a bird, then `X` can fly* which is easily expressible in Prolog and doesn't need `findall`.

Comment: Could you please correct the lower and capital letter for me. yes you are right. but i want to learn using `forall` and `\+` with a simple example

Comment: I indicated lower case first letter represents an *atom* (specific instance of a variable) and upper case first letter is a variable. You will need to take that into account to figure out how you want to state your problem. `forall` is used to find *all* solutions to a given query. It's not used to express a *universal quantifier*.

Comment: If you want to say, for example, *All mammals are `b`* using `findall`, you could use `findall` to collect all of the mammals for which `b` is not provable (`mammal(M), \+ b(M)`) and succeed if the result is the empty list `[]`. You should read up on `findall` and give some things a try and show in your question what you've tried and where you get stuck.